# Type '{ id: any; user_ip: any; user_Agent: any; url: any; urlReferer: any; }' is not assignable to type '(IntrinsicAttributes

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
react: "^16.12.0",   
react-dom: "^16.12.0",   
@types/react: "^16.9.49",   
typescript: "^4.0.3"
```

How do I resolve the above mentioned type issue on the following code when attempting to pass props to a component?:

pages/item.tsx

```
import SingleItem from '../components/SingleItem';
import { withRouter } from "next/router";

const Item = props => (
  <div>
    <SingleItem id={props.query.id} user_ip={props.userIP} user_Agent={props.userAgent} url={props.router.asPath} urlReferer={props.urlReferer} />
  </div>
);

export default withRouter(Item);
```

The error message in full reads as:

```
Type '{ id: any; user_ip: any; user_Agent: any; url: any; urlReferer: any; }' is not assignable to type '(IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<WithRouterProps, never> & { children?: ReactNode; }) | (IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<...> & RefAttributes<...>)'.
  Property 'id' does not exist on type '(IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<WithRouterProps, never> & { children?: ReactNode; }) | (IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<...> & RefAttributes<...>)'.ts(2322)
```

My partial repo can be found here: https://github.com/TheoMer/next_apollo

Comment: Tagged `typescript` but using JSX? So... is this really a `typescript` question? Looks like JavaScript to me, otherwise you'd be using the `.tsx` extension, right?

Comment: @spender That was a typo. The file extension should indeed have read tsx, which I have now changed

Answer (score 0):

Lots to cover here.

First of all, this is a function-component, so it should be declared as `FC<T>`.

You should also

```
import React from "react"
```

in *all* tsx files. It's a requirement.

The preference for function-components is to use hooks, so ditch `withRouter` and [start using `useRouter` instead](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#userouter).

The generic type `T` of `FC<T>` declares the component props.

Putting this all together, your component should look something like this:

```
import SingleItem from '../components/SingleItem';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import React, {FC} from "react";

interface ItemProps{
    query:{ //there's probably a `Query` type IDK about
        id:string;
    };
    userIP:string;
    userAgent:string;
    urlReferer:string;
}

const Item:FC<ItemProps> = (props) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  return(
      <div>
        <SingleItem 
            id={props.query.id} 
            user_ip={props.userIP} 
            user_Agent={props.userAgent} 
            url={router.asPath} 
            urlReferer={props.urlReferer} />
      </div>)
};
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response. Unfortunately I am now getting the following error message: Type '{ id: string; user_ip: string; user_Agent: string; url: string; urlReferer: string; }' is not assignable to type '(IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<WithRouterProps, never> & { children?: ReactNode; }) | (IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<...> & RefAttributes<...>)'.
  Property 'id' does not exist on type '(IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<WithRouterProps, never> & { children?: ReactNode; }) | (IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<...> & RefAttributes<...>)'.ts(2322)

Comment: You must still be using `withRouter`. Don't

Comment: Removing withRouter from the child component resolved the issue. Many thanks.